# How to use regex with grep

Tags: regex, grep

I just used the following grep command:

```
grep -ri '^(<topicref |<mapref).*( )(dest=")'
```

to match the following:

```
<topicref version="1" dest="susu"/>
<mapref id="" dest="summat"/>
```

all topicref and mapref that have a dest attribute.

However, it didnt work although regexpal accepts the regex. How do I have to change this to work with grep?

Comment: Use the `-E` option to use extended regexp.

Comment: or escape all `(`, `)`, `|` with a backslash: `grep -ri '^\(<topicref \|<mapref\).*\( \)\(dest="\)'`

Comment: This is explicitly mentioned in `man grep`...

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use parentheses and alternation without using extended regular expressions, you can escape them with the backslash to enable this functionality.

```
grep -ir '^\(<topicref \|<mapref\).*\( \)\(dest="\)' .
```

Or, you can use `-E` option, and then you do not have to escape brackets:

```
grep -iEr '^(<topicref |<mapref).*( )(dest=")' .
```

Mind the `.` at the end stands for the current directory, and together with `r` recursive option, this will  fetch you all the matches in the directory files.